# Is it possible to filter by the 'year' of a 'date field' while using the Wagtail v2 API and search_fields in the model

Tags: wagtail-apiv2, wagtail-search

## What we are building

We are building a Wagtail 4.2.4 implementation that allows an admin user to add content through the GUI. One field in the model of that content type (or app) is a date field which uses a datepicker to select the published date field in the GUI.

All the content associated with the content type (very similar to the [default blog example from wagtail](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/v4.2.4/getting_started/tutorial.html)) is then served via an API for the front end to consume.

One of the front-end requirements is to filter by **year** , to make this easier for the dev I would like to make the API call itself filterable by year.

## What I have tried

I have scoured [all documentation](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/v4.2.4/advanced_topics/api/index.html) and approaches and have come to nought. Ideally, we need a similar queryset result method to `models.blog.objects.all().filter(date__year=year)` but instead a `index.FilterField('date_year'),` type approach inside **search_fields** .

Below is the simplified model from models.py which shows how the date field is currently implemented along with search_field and api_fields.

Note that adding a serialized date field `date_year` by changing the formating didn't work.

## Model

```
class BlogPage(Page):

    date = models.DateField("Post date")

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        ...
        FieldPanel('date'),
        ...
    ]

    search_fields = Page.search_fields + [
        ...
        index.FilterField('date'),
        ...
    ]

    api_fields = [
        ...
        APIField('date'),
        APIField('date_year', serializer=DateField(format='%Y', source='date')),
        ...
    ]
```